# About didRangeBeaconsInRegion

Tags: java, android, beacon, altbeacon

I calculated user located by beacons and then want to paint user located by canvas
I do it, but the background will continues called due to
**didRangeBeaconsInRegion** it is loop, it will continues detection region beacons caused background will continues called.
This my part of the program

**DrawView.java**

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    ReceiveLocate activity;
    Bitmap bp,bg;
    Paint paint;
    public DrawView(Context context){
        super(context);
        this.activity = (ReceiveLocate) context;
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(25);
        bp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
                   R.drawable.greendot1);
     }
     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onDraw(canvas);
          canvas.drawText("座標 : (" + activity.X+", "+activity.Y+")", 5, 30, 
                        paint);
          canvas.drawCircle(activity.X, activity.Y, 10, paint);
          System.out.println("當前座標 = ("+activity.X+", "+activity.Y+")");
     }
}
```

**Main2Activity.java**

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {
      protected static final  String TAG = "Main2Activity";
      private BeaconManager beaconManager = 
                 BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
```

I try to write directly in Main2Activity.java, but call **extends View** and **extend Activity** are different. How to improve the background has been called the problem?

Comment: Can you please clarify what is not working with the code you have shown?

Comment: It is working, but it will continue call backgrounds. I have sent mail to you for video and my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to get ranging callbacks when your app is not in the foreground you can do one of two things:

1. Implement an `onPause()` method in your Activity, and stop ranging there, then also implement an `onResume()` method in your Activity and restart ranging there.
2. You can use the BackgroundPowerSaver class as described here: 
   https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html.  By default, it will still do ranging in the background once every 5 minutes, but you can customize this to be effectively never by calling `beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(Long.MAX_VALUE);`

Comment: Sorry. I think... I did not explain it clearly.  I want to express that it can work, but I write `android:background="@drawable/background1` import image as background in `activity_main2.xml`. Because `public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) ` it will continue detect region beacon cause I paint user locate and background will keep on paint new View in `DrawView`. I want to continue update user locate but the background is not. What should I do?

Comment: Do you want it to continue processing the detections in the background or not?

Comment: Yes, I need to continue processing. It can be updated for user positioning.

Comment: There `background` means `picture` .